# LG android phone emulator

Tags: android-emulator, lg, emulators

Is there an LG phone emulator to test android apps on ?
Since some LG phones show different behavior from other devices.

Answer (score 2):

Nexus 5 (LG D820) emulator images are readily available from Android Studio.
**Tools--> Android--> AVD Manager --> Nexus 5**